# How to show the errors through ajax and Jquery in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my ajax call

```
function exportCSV(){
        var sampleid = $("#sampleid").val();
        var scheme = $("#scheme").val();
        var v = $("#v").val();
        var date = $("#date").val();
        var assignedvalue = $("#assignedvalue").val();
        var units = $("#units").val();
        var assayvalue = $("#assayvalue").val();
        var analyte = $("#analyte").val();
        var filename=$("#filename").val();
        var sample_error=$("#sample_error").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "import/validate_file",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                sampleid: sampleid,
                scheme: scheme,
                v: v,
                date: date,
                assignedvalue: assignedvalue,
                units: units,
                assayvalue: assayvalue,
                analyte: analyte,
                filename:filename,
                sample_error: sample_error
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);  //as a debugging message.
            }

        });
    }
```

and this is my controller

```
<?php
if (!empty($unit_check) and !empty($analyt) and !empty($sch) and count($sample_id) == count(array_unique($sample_id)) and $assigned_check == '1' and $assay_check == '1') {
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
        $data['sample_id']      = $worksheet->getCell($sampleid . $row)->getValue();
        $data['scheme']         = $worksheet->getCell($scheme . $row)->getValue();
        $data['v']              = $worksheet->getCell($v . $row)->getValue();
        $data['units']          = $worksheet->getCell($unit . $row)->getValue();
        $data['date']           = $worksheet->getCell($date . $row)->getFormattedValue();
        $data['assay_value']    = $worksheet->getCell($assayvalue . $row)->getValue();
        $data['assigned_value'] = $worksheet->getCell($assignedvalue . $row)->getValue();
        $data['analyte']        = $worksheet->getCell($analyte . $row)->getValue();
        $data['trace_id']       = $insert_id;
        $this->import_model->insert_data($data);
        $response['success'] = true;
    }
} else {
    $data['sample_id']      = '';
    $data['analyte']        = '';
    $data['unit_check']     = '';
    $data['sch']            = '';
    $data['assigned_value'] = '';
    $data['assay_value']    = '';
    if (count($sample_id) != count(array_unique($sample_id))) {
        $data['sample_id'] = '1';
    }
    if (empty($analyt)) {
        $data['analyte'] = '1';
    }
    if (empty($unit_check)) {
        $data['unit_check'] = '1';
    }
    if (empty($sch)) {
        $data['sch'] = '1';
    }
    if ($assigned_check == '') {
        $data['assigned_value'] = '1';
    }
    if ($assay_check == '') {
        $data['assay_value'] = '1';
    }
    $data['file_name'] = '';
}
?>
```

I have to show the errors and success message on ajax call.

Right now I'm succeeded in valuating the data and putting it in the database.

But I want to show the success message at the end of the page by clicking the submit button.

And if there is validations error it must shows the errors in that fields at the end of the page

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: return some data as success or failed to your AJAx, and then create a HTML element to show your result. inside your success method use that element to show your result

Comment: @SSingh Can you plz provide me a link about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here inside your success method of ajax

```
success: function (data) {
   $("#resultDiv").html(data)
}
```

Return some real data from your controller in both case success and failed. and based on your data inside success method show your message.
Like:

```
success: function (data) {
     $("#resultDiv").html(data.success) //this requires string to convert your result in string if neccessary
     //But you should return a JSON data as msg from your controller
}
```

You should put a result HTML element for example:

```
<div id='resultDiv'></div> <!-- to match with #resultDiv -->
```

Put response data in both condition if `success=true` and else `success=false`

**In your controller**

```
if(.....){
  //what ever check you wanna do
  ..........
  ..........
  $response['msg']='success';
  header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
  $response['msg']='failed';
  header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

**In your ajax**

```
success: function (data) {
   $("#resultDiv").html(data.msg)
}
```

Comment: actually right now i m only sending the checks upon valdiation like if is_unique(array) { $data['success'] = true;}

Comment: see your console what you are getting from your each AJAX Call

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$response = array(
    'errCode' = 0,
    'errMsg'  = 'msg'
);
```

return this kind of array by json_encode() from php to ajax() call and use it in ajax() success like:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);

alert(data.errMsg);
```

You can also put a check on errCode like:

```
if(errCode == 0) { something }
if(errCode == 1) { something }
```

Comment: so i should do this after parsing like if(data.errCode==0){ something} ??

Comment: No, after parsing.